# Ajax succes function is not getting called

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have a form which executes perfectly, the only thing not working is the success function getting triggered although the form values are added to the database.

-- UPDATED CODE --

Well this is the whole code right now.

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
$('#taakstarten').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var loader = $('#loader');
    var loaderHTML = '<img src="loader.gif" /> Taak gestart';
    var post_url = form.attr('action');
    var post_data = form.serialize();
    $(loader, form).html('<img src="loader.gif" /> Taak starten...');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: post_url, 
        data: post_data,
        success: function() 
        {
            form.html(loaderHTML);
        }
    });
});
```

});

PHP:

```
<?php
include('../functions.php');
    $onderwerp = sql_quote($_POST["onderwerp"]);
    $omschrijving = sql_quote($_POST["omschrijving"]);
    $verantwoordelijke = sql_quote($_POST["verantwoordelijke"]);
    $e_datum = strtotime(sql_quote($_POST["e_datum"]));
    $b_datum = time();
    $frequentie = sql_quote($_POST["frequentie"]);
    $klant = sql_quote($_POST["klant"]);
    $userid = sql_quote($_POST["userid"]);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `taken` (
            `naam`,
            `t_door`,
            `omschrijving`,
            `verantwoordelijke`,
            `b_datum`,
            `e_datum`,
            `klant`) VALUES (
            '$onderwerp',
            '$userid',
            '$omschrijving',
            '$verantwoordelijke',
            '$b_datum',
            '$e_datum',
            '$klant')";
            mysql_query($sql);
echo('ok');
?>
```

Comment: remove the header and just `echo 'ok'`, you apparently have no data to send back, so there's no reason to use json.

Comment: add `contentType: application/json` in $.ajax call

Comment: @Murali he isn't sending json to the server, therefore that param could actually make the request not work.

Comment: Both did not work for me, the first loader.html is getting called and the php executes well. But the succes function is not updating the loader to its new state.

Comment: If you put an alert in the success function (comment out the other stuff) is it called?

Comment: @SteveWellens no even the alert is not being called

Comment: Put in an error function handler and see if IT is called.

Comment: Have you seen if the request is rejected or error out in the Browser Console?

Comment: @Djavier89 there is no error or rejection by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to use HTML Objects as selectors:

change:

```
var form = $(this);
var loader = $('#loader');
$(loader, form).html('<img src="loader.gif" /> Taak gestart');
```

to:

```
var form = $(this);
var loader = $('#loader');
var loaderHTML = '<img src="loader.gif" /> Taak gestart';
form.html(loaderHTML);
loader.html(loaderHTML);
```

Comment: So I actually do not need a succes function at all? cause if I place those .html inside the succes function it's not being called. Although if I place it like you did, the form replaces with a 'succes' message which actually does the trick. But it's not done through the succes function.

Comment: maybe you have two kind of problems: the success function is not called (just debug it!) and jquery has no problem (no errors) if you do something like $($('#loader')). becouse in your code you actually try to select a whole HTMLObject while jquery wants some string as selector. i dont know if you "need" a success function. you have to decide if you want to display your stuff right after the submit or just when you get a response from php.

Comment: Well I actually preffer a succes function, cause if my mysql_query fails I would like to send that error back.

Comment: ok there are already good comments you should check. the success function from jquery side looks ok maybe you want to feed us with some php. becouse if not even an alert is called in the success function your problem is on php side. but be sure you also fix your jquery selector thing i posted as answer, becouse if you fix the php side you will still have no updates on your loader and form with your old js code

Comment: var post_url = form.attr('action'); has this target the same origin like your domain has?